# See if there is a vowel before letter 'y' in a string

Tags: python, string

```
x = input()
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
```

I am trying to use an `if` statement that shows if `y` is in the string (without knowing the position of the `y` in the string).

If there are any vowels before `y`, `print(1)`; if not `print (2)`, and if there is no `y` in the word `print(3)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

word = "wordy"
ypos = word.find("y")

if ypos != -1:
    if(bool(re.search(('|'.join(["a","e","i","o","u"])),word[:ypos]))):
        print("1")
    else:
        print("2")
else :
    print("3")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> def y_in_word(word):
...     if 'y' not in word:
...             print 3
...     elif any([x in word for x in ['ay', 'ey', 'iy', 'oy', 'uy']]):
...             print 2
...     else:
...             print 1
...
>>>
>>> y_in_word('wordy')
1
>>> y_in_word('worday')
2
>>> y_in_word('worda')
3
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using regex:

```
x = input()
vowels = "aeiou"

for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i] == "y":
        break

if x[i] != "y":  # No y found
    print(3)
else:
    flag = 0
    new_str = x[:i+1]
    for ch in new_str:
        if ch in vowels:
            print(1)
            flag += 1
            break

    if flag == 0:
        print(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = input()
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

if 'y' in x:
    # find the position of 'y' in the input string
    y_position = x.index(y)

    # loop through each vowel
    for vowel in vowels:
        # if the vowel is in the input string and its position is before y
        if vowel in x and x.index(vowel) < y_position:
            print(1)
            break

    # if we made it all the way through the loop without breaking, we did not find
    # any vowels before y
    else:
        print(2)

else:
    print(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

First become lowercase and then judge

```
import re
x = input().lower()
m = re.findall("(?=a|e|i|o|u)\w*?(?=y)",x)
if "y" in x.lower():
    if m:
        print(1)
    else:
        print(2)
else:
    print(3)
```